# No transaction is currently active

Tags: java

So I have this code

```
public static void insert(User user) {
    EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEmFactory().createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
    trans.begin();        
    try {
        em.persist(user);
        trans.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        trans.rollback();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

but when I run I get this error

[image: picture]

Comment: post error as code as well

Comment: Looks like the server is missing something here, as in, you should have send something before this. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 2):

You need to check first if the transaction is active thanks to [`EntityTransaction#isActive()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityTransaction.html#isActive--) before calling `rollback()`.

The *non-managed environment* idiom is:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();

    // do some work
    ...

    tx.commit();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if ( tx != null && tx.isActive() ) tx.rollback();
    throw e; // or display error message
}
finally {
    em.close();
}
```

For more details check [§5.2.1](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged) from the hibernate's documentation.

So in your case the code should rather be:

```
EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEmFactory().createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction trans = null;
try {
    trans = em.getTransaction();
    trans.begin();
    em.persist(user);
    trans.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    if (trans != null && trans.isActive())
        trans.rollback();
} finally {
    em.close();
}
```